# Is it safe to remove old versions of the Azure Tools & Libraries?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have kept up to date with the Azure tooling for Visual Studio but the installers do not remove any previous versions so I am left with many versions:

[image: Many Azure versions]

Is it safe to remove all but the latest?

Comment: Does your code make use of latest version of tooling? If so, then it is safe to remove them. Azure team enabled side-by-side installation of SDKs just in case you have 2 applications making use of different versions.

Comment: Ah, I see... All our production code will be using an older version, not sure which! If I removed the older versions would it be easy enough to update to use the latest version if/when we need to make any changes?

Comment: Are your applications `Cloud Services`? If so, you can check the SDK version by opening up Cloud Service Project properties and it will tell you which version of SDK is being used.